# Show different table id based on radio button selection JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a different table id based on radio button selection. I have made a start but really cannot see where I am going wrong with the IF STATEMENT.

The table should change based on radio button selection. Any help would be very appreciated. thanks

```
<tr>
    <td>Select An Option:</td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <input id="selection1" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge" checked="checked">
            Charge me
            </option></br>

            <input id="selection2" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge1">
            another option, no display
            </option><br/>    

            <input id="selection3" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge2" >    
            another option, no display 
            </option><br/>   
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name="group1"]').change(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "charge") {
                $('#charge').css('display', 'inline');
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == "charge1") {
                $('#charge1').css('display', 'inline');
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == "charge2")
            {
                $('#charge2').css('display', 'inline');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="charge"></table>
<table id="charge1"></table>
<table id="charge2"></table>
```

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/LbL19v70/ The `table` elements aren't appearing in your example as they have no content in them.

Comment: Also, note that your `if` statement is redundant: http://jsfiddle.net/LbL19v70/1/

Comment: Yes, it does work to a certain extent but a little bit more is required to achieve desired result which is to only show one table id at a time when radio button is selected. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would fix your html for the inputs - you  have closing `option` tags and a `br` that has the backslash in the wrong place.

Next I would give all your charge tables a class and then you can use the value of the radio to show the table you want to.

```js
var tables = $('.charge-table');
$('input[name="group1"]').on('change', function() {
  tables.hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```css
.charge-table {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="selection1" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge">Charge me
  <br/>
  <input id="selection2" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge1">another option, no display
  <br/>
  <input id="selection3" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge2">another option, no display
  <br/>
</div>


<table id="charge" class="charge-table">
  <tr>
    <td>charge</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="charge1" class="charge-table">
  <tr>
    <td>charge 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="charge2" class="charge-table">
  <tr>
    <td>charge 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: WOW! Lesson learned. Works like a dream, it is exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Hi Pete, one more thing - I have checked the rad btn but on page load table 'charge' is not showing?

Comment: Just add it to your css: `#charge {display:table;}`

Comment: Hi Pete, just have a new requirement and wondered whether you could be of help?  I want to add another row of options below the current ones to allow the user to select between inch and cm based on the above selection made. I'm fine with the html and css but not quite sure on the script that I will need to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, I think you should open another question for that so that you can give it  a bit more explanation and some example code

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name="group1"]').change(function(){
            if ($("input[name='group1']:checked").val() == "charge")
          {
            $('#selection1').css('display', 'inline');
           }

            else if ($("input[name='group1']:checked").val() == "charge1")
           {
            $('#selection2').css('display', 'inline');
          }

            else if ($("input[name='group1']:checked").val() == "charge2")
          {
            $('#selection3').css('display', 'inline');
          }

        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just further to Petes answer, this is how I would of achieved it

```js
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
   var tableId  = $("input[type=radio][id="+ this.id + "]").val();
    
     $("#charge1").css('display', 'none');
     $("#charge").css('display', 'none');
     $("#charge2").css('display', 'none');
    
    $("#" + tableId).css('display', 'inline');
    
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="selection1" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge">Charge me
  <br/>
  <input id="selection2" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge1">another option, no display
  <br/>
  <input id="selection3" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge2">another option, no display
  <br/>
</div>


<table id="charge" class="charge-table">
  <tr>
    <td>charge</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="charge1" class="charge-table">
  <tr>
    <td>charge 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="charge2" class="charge-table">
  <tr>
    <td>charge 2</td>
  </tr>
</table
```

See JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wfpfg2gu/1/

Comment: using `display:inline` to show a table is a bad idea - see what happens to the layout when you click on charge 1 from it's initial layout